# It this the correct way of extending eslint rules?

Tags: yaml, eslint

In my `eslint` config (`YAML` format), I'm extending 3 different configurations:

```
extends:
- airbnb-base
- plugin:angular/johnpapa
- ionic
```

My questions are as follows:

- Is this the correct format in `YAML`?
- Some of these extensions have overlapping rules (or multiple of them extend `eslint:recommended`): will I get the same error multiple times if the error is related to one of these "shared" rules?

Answer (score 11):

At first, **Yes, it's the correct format in YAML** (see for example [ESLint - Configuring Plugins](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-plugins)). As JSON, it would be

```
{
  "extends": [
    "airbnb-base",
    "plugin:angular/johnpapa",
    "ionic"
  ]
}
```

If you have multiple rulesets in your `extend` section, each following ruleset will extend or overwrite the previous ones. So you will only have one setting for each rule (see [ESLint - Extending Configuration Files](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#extending-configuration-files)) Sometimes when the rules from the shareable configs are conflicting and you can't define a specific order for the `extend` section you have to manually define this specific rule in you `rules` section.

So the answer to you second question is: **No, you won't get the same error multiple times**.

Answer (score -5):

The correct way to extend `eslint` rules is like so:

```
extends: ["standard", "plugin:jest/recommended"]
```